# Best way to model multi-dimensional input to minimize KL divergence?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

My input has a dimension of 496x2 which represents 496 different features and their parameters that are two values. The output is a distribution of these 496 features such that they sum to 1.0.

I am trying to model this with a Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP). I found that I must flatten the input after the first hidden layer to make it run. This is the working model I have:

```
  model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=(496,2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
  model.add(Dense(496, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='kl_divergence')
```

KL divergence was chosen as I am minimizing the difference between two distributions with 496 possible features.

To some extent the above model works but I would like to have a better model. The problem with the current model is that it doesn't take into account of the positional correspondence of the inputs and outputs. The flatten layer also mixes up the first parameter and the second parameter of each feature. Is there a better model for this problem? Thank you very much in advance.